# Issues running pip install, having checked all known solutions

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am having issues running the most simple of codes, despite my experience. On a work computer, having been granted admin rights, I downloaded python. I clicked install as admin and add to path upon installation.

I then try to run a pip install, however get the following issues:

I tried:

`pip install numpy`

output:

`File "<stdin>", line 1 pip install numpy ^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I then tried checking for common issues, like not having pip, so within python console did:

`import sys print(sys.version)`

output:

`3.12.0 (tags/v3.12.0:0fb18b0, Oct  2 2023, 13:03:39) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)]`

Then on windows command prompt:

`pip --version`

output:

`pip 23.2.1 from C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.12)`

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying this command on Jupyter?

Comment: No within the python command prompt, then also within Spyder, same results

Comment: You dont have to start python at terminal, Just type at windows command prompt 
pip install numpy

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have got it working now.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct, if it, solved your issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to start python at terminal, Just type at windows command prompt

pip install numpy